# SQL apply a function to all data in a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, spatialite

I am new to SQL. I am working on Spatialite which is a spatial database build on top of SQLite. I want to apply the function LineStringFromText() to all data in a column called "geometry". I tried the SQL statement below, but I get synax erors:

> SQL error:"Near" "Select" Synax Error"

```
UPDATE test1f
SET geometry = SELECT LineStringFromText(geometry) from test1f
```

Comment: You did not share the sql statement, nor the exact error message with us. How do you expect us to help? Btw, mysql is a completely different rdbms product. Pls only use the relevant product tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You over-engineered it.  Change this:

```
SET geometry = SELECT LineStringFromText(geometry) from test1f
```

to this

```
SET geometry = LineStringFromText(geometry)
```